# Ordering CharField form choices in Django

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I currently have a form that I am creating via `django.forms.ModelForm`. I've listed the choices for one of the CharFields that is in the form, but upon translation, the choices are of course out of order -- they remain in the order that they were listed in `models.py`. I'd like for the choices to be alphabetized in the translated language. How can I go ahead and translate them, and then order them, so that in the form, they are listed in alphabetical order?

I think I might have to override the `__init__` method for self.fields, but have not been able to do so in a way that successfully re-orders my categories.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    SORTED_CATEGORIES = sorted(CATEGORIES)
    self.fields['category'].choices = SORTED_CATEGORIES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting in the `__init__` method looks ok. Remember that only the second item in the tuple gets translated, so you want to sort based on that.

```
SORTED_CATEGORIES = sorted(CATEGORIES, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I wasn't sorting by the second item initially because both the value that is stored in the DB and its label are the same -- but of course, only the label gets translated, so we have to sort by that :) Thanks!